# Using gekko MV's and CV's outside of a MHE or MPC simulation

Tags: python, gekko

I am making a hybrid energy system and I am trying to have `gekko` solve to minimize the cost. I have 3 CV arrays that I am trying to adjust my generated electricity to fit. When I go to solve the system I keep getting the error that my arrays are miss matched, I think that this is due to me not using a time array. Is there a way to have gekko in python solve this system without having to use a time array? Also can I use MVs if I am not using a MPC or MHE method?

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as plt

m.time = np.linspace(0,10,20)

Esolar = np.linspace(0,10,20)
Ewind  = np.linspace(10,0,20)
Econs  = np.linspace(0,30,20)

m = GEKKO()
Es = m.CV(value = Esolar)
Ew = m.CV(value = Ewind)
Ec = m.CV(value = Econs)

Etherm = m.MV(value = 0, lb = 0, ub = 10)
Enuc = m.MV(value = 0, lb = 0, ub = 40)
Egen = m.Intermediate(Etherm + Enuc)

m.Equation(0 == Egen + Es + Ew - Ec)
m.Obj(Enuc*.05 + Etherm*.1)       #Thermal Energy storage is twice as expensive

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve()
```

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with using MVs for any mode. The function of the MV changes with different modes. For example, `STATUS` doesn't do anything in simulation mode `IMODE=4` but it does turn ON (1) or OFF (0) the degrees of freedom in optimization modes such as `IMODE=6` (MPC).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`m.time` is placed before the definition of `m` as `GEKKO()`